# How to query a date range from two columns in MySQL using Python

Tags: mysql, datetime, python-3.x

I'm using Python34 working with a MySQL database that has a table with a `sent_time` and `delivered_time` column. I am trying to get all the orders that fall between two datetime inputs but I'm only getting the script to look at `sent_time` and not both `sent_time` and `delivered_time`.

So in other words, I'm looking to find all the objects that were sent, in process of being delivered or delivered within a given timeframe.

```
query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, OBJ, id1, id2 FROM table1 "
    "WHERE sent_time BETWEEN %s AND %s"
)
userIn = dateutil.parser.parse(input('start date:'))
userEnd = dateutil.parser.parse(input('end date:'))
```

I tried changing the query to be `WHERE sent_time or delivered_time BETWEEN %S AND %s` but that just returns the entire table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SQL syntax is:

```
WHERE sent_time  BETWEEN %s AND %e 
OR delivered_time BETWEEN %s AND %e
```

s for start, e for end, both those points are included in the results.

or, perhaps for your needs:

```
WHERE %s between sent_time and delivered_time
```

While not apparent to all, using BETWEEN is problematical for date ranges, and the best practice is to use >= with < instead.

e.g. to get absolutely everything for the year 2015, but absolutely nothing after (or before) that year, then:

```
select * from sometable
where datecolumn >= '2015-01-01' and datecolumn < '2016-01-01'
```

Regardless of data precision (day? second? millisecond?) that construct will be accurate

Comment: how can I make it look at userIn and userEnd for your given syntax?

Comment: because it is saying I don't have enough parameters

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%e delivered_time BETWEEN '2015-09-13 14:12:11' AND %e' at line 1

Comment: if you supplied sample data (including parameter values) and the expected result your question would be easier to accurately answer, I have attempted to correct your SQL but offer no python code.

Comment: one thought is to invert the comparisons e.g. `%s between sent_time and delivered_time` but without facts I am guessing

Comment: it worked when i used '"WHERE (sent_time >= %s and delivered_time <= %s)"'

Comment: Great! if you look at my text about not using between you will see that I use less than only, not <= and that is important. **If you do need both points included in the result then stay with what you have** (or use between) but in my example 2016-01-01 is NOT included, just everything less than that point.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an extra between condition for the delivered_time field as well:

```
query = (
    "SELECT sent_time, delivered_time, OBJ, id1, id2 FROM table1 "
    "WHERE (sent_time BETWEEN %s AND %s) OR (delivered_time BETWEEN %s AND %s)"
)
```

You need to determine, if you need `or` or `and` to combine the 2 criteria. It's not clear to me from the question.

Comment: I'm sure **you** can also determine which of the 2 should be used.